# Present or show message or a link once a desired operation is done[like checkbox checked] in JSP[Java]

Tags: java, jsp

I am currently learning JSP. I have a list of fruits with check boxes next to each fruit. I want to show a message or a link once a user select one or more fruit and submits. How could I achieve it? Here is my code.By the way my code is not working...

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<title>JSP Multiple Checkbox</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form1" action="">
<h3>Select your favorite Fruits</h3>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Mango"/>Mango</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Apple"/>Apple</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Grapes"/>Grapes</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Papaya"/>Papaya</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Lychee"/>Lychee</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Pineapple"/>Pineapple</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="submit"/> 
</form>


<%

String select[] = request.getParameterValues("id"); 
if (select != null && select.length != 0) {
out.println("You have selected: ");
for (int i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
out.println(select[i]); 
}

    //show message or a link instead of printing
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that JSP is executed on the server-side. What you want to do is to dynamically display something on the client-side when an user interact. This could not be done with taglib or directly in JSP, since your JSP can not know what the user is doing. JSP just allow you to generate HTML that will be send to the client-side. After that, JSP does not interfer.
There is two ways to do that:

- using JavaScript: it will allow you to dynamise your client-side. You will add a `onChange` event on your checkbox and, in this event, make some actions on the interface;
- using Ajax: you will use JavaScript for this too. But you will handle the Asynchronous request in server-side, then you will process treatment on the server, and finally you will send a response to the client-side (HTML, JSON...).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the 'action' parameter of the form to another jsp file and move the lines

```
<%

String select[] = request.getParameterValues("fruit"); 
if (select != null && select.length != 0) {
out.println("You have selected: ");
for (int i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
out.println(select[i]); 
}

 //show message or a link instead of printing
}
%>
```

To the new jsp.
To show a message or link, you need to use javascript.
PS: the line request.getParameterValues("id")
is wrong. Give
    request.getParameterValues("fruit")